# View setEnabled() Error : NullPointerException

Tags: android, for-loop, view, nullpointerexception

I tried to set views to Enabled(false), but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)'
on a null object reference
```

Something I don't understand is that the error didn't occur at `ccl_stage11[][]` but occured at `vtl_stage11` and `hrl_stage11[][]` even though they're using same `for` in the same way.

I tried to unroll the 'for' loop at the setEnabled part, but it didn't work. 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Here is the code related to this error.

```
public class Stage1Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button[][] ccl_stage11 = new Button[4][4];
    Button[][] hrl_stage11 = new Button[4][4];
    Button[][] vtl_stage11 = new Button[4][4];



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stage11);


        buttonSettings();
}
 protected void buttonSettings() {


        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                ccl_stage11[i][j] = findViewById(R.id.ccl_stage11_11 + k);
                ccl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                k++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                vtl_stage11[i][j] = findViewById(R.id.vtl_stage11_00 + k);
                hrl_stage11[i][j] = findViewById(R.id.hrl_stage11_00 + k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<=3;j++){
                vtl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                hrl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        ccl_stage11[1][3].setEnabled(true);
        ccl_stage11[3][1].setEnabled(true);


    }
```

The error occurs at

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    for (int j =0;j<=3;j++){
        vtl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
        hrl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your XML file too

Comment: While checking for the `null` might solve your `Exception`, but the problem is still there. Also if you've to show many buttons that do the same tasks, why don't you use `RecyclerView`, `GridView` or `ListView` whichever is appropriate for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `null`'s before you do anything.

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    for (int j =0;j<=3;j++){

        // add this condition!
        if(vtl_stage11[i][j] != null) {
            vtl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            hrl_stage11[i][j].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```